# Passing axios data from a utility file to a component

Tags: reactjs, axios

In my React app I'm using axios to return data from an API.

**api-helper.js**

```
export const getData = async () => {
    axios
        .get(API_DOMAIN)
        .then(response => {
            const resp = response.data;
            console.log(resp);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('get error', error));
};
```

In the console log, the JSON data is returned correctly:

```
{
"content": {
"code": "CAT33",
"name": "Death Star ",
"slug": "death-start-",
"trustFriendlySlug": false,
"description": "",
"facetFilters": [
...// additional data
```

However, in my parent component when I try to use this data in `ComponentDidMount`, It is returning an HTML string instead of the JSON data:

```
data: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵  <head>↵    
headers: {accept-ranges: "bytes", connection: "keep-alive", content-encoding: "gzip", content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", date: "Fri, 08 Jan 2021 15:49:27 GMT", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCreden
```

**parentComponent.js**

```
import { getData } from '../../utils/api-helper';


class parentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

                this.state = {
                   content: {
                     code: '',
                     name: '',
                     facetFilters: [],
                   },
               };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(getData()).then(result => {
            console.log('result', result);
            this.setState({ result });
        });
    }
}
```

I thought using `axios.get` in `componentDidMount` along with the request from my api-helper would display the same result. What is the correct way to import data. I've looked at examples such as [How to get valid JSON response from axios library using nodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621959/how-to-get-valid-json-response-from-axios-library-using-nodejs) & [Can't set state in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775699/cant-set-state-in-react)

However, unlike those answers, I am trying to pass the data down from my parent component into other components. What is the correct way to handle this data?

Comment: you are doing `axios.get(getData())`, you already have an `axios.get` inside `getData()`, just check what `getData()` returns, plus return in that function, or pass the api_domain instead of `getData()` in componentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first need to return inside your helper function then on your component did mount await the response and set that to state

```
export const getData = async () => {
let resp
   await axios
        .get(API_DOMAIN)
        .then(response => {
            resp = response.data;
            console.log(resp);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('get error', error));
return resp
};
```

```
componentDidMount() {
async function fetchInitial(){

const resp = await getData()
console.log(resp)
}
fetchInitial()
}
```

Comment: for some reason, this returned my data in the helper function as ```undefined```. However, I rewrote the helper function and used your solution for componentDidMount to finally get it working. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: glad i could help.  yeah I couldn't test my solution as thoroughly as I wouldve liked since I don't know what api you're pulling from, but as long as you were able to come out with a solution.